# Python efficient/simple ways to calculate the sum of two array of values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, I need to find the sum of the products of two lists of numbers:

```
numbers=[1,2,3]
numba = [4,5,6]

result = []
for list1,list2 in zip(numbers,numba):
    f_1 = float(list1)
    f_2 = float(list2)
    pro = f_1 * f_2
    result.append(pro)
print(sum(result))
```

Currently I have to create a new list outside the for loop to proceed getting the sum of the product values. So I am curious are there more efficient ways in default Python to get the sum without setting up a new list to store the products in order to perform calculations?

(Mathematically the formula would be `a*a2 + b*b2 + c*c2`)

Comment: Why don't you provide the desired output in the question itself - why would you have us guess what `a*a2 + b*b2 + c*c2` means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use (generator) comprehension to simplify the task.

```py
numbers=[1,2,3]
numba = [4,5,6]

print(sum(x * y for x, y in zip(numbers, numba))) # 32
```

Comment: Try not to use language like `"why don't you just use <insert some technical jargon a beginner isn't going to understand>"`. It's unproductive and condescending.

Comment: @ddejohn Oh I see, didn't know it had condescending connotation. I apologize. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, +1. Try to remember that we were all new to programming at one point!

Comment: New to Python. Don't quiet understand comprehension form.

Comment: @PeanutJams there's probably a primer on comprehensions somewhere, that might interest you; but essentially, comprehensions are just a short, neat way of writing for loops!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to store a list, you can just keep track of the total:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
numba = [4, 5, 6]

result = 0.0
for a, b in zip(numbers, numba):
    result += a * b

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **reduce** and **map**:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add,mul

numbers=[1,2,3]
numba = [4,5,6]
print(reduce(add,map(mul,numbers,numba)))
```

Output:

```
32
```

Comment: This won't work when the lists are empty.